# Parse string map correct labels

Tags: python, regex, string, tree

Assume we have the following *unlabeled* parse string:

```
s = "(S (S Now) (S (S we) (S (S 're) (S (S at) (S (S (S the) (S bottom)) (S (S of) (S (S the) (S heap))))))))"
```

Assume we have somehow extracted it's *constituents*:

```
constituents = ['the bottom',
                'the heap',
                'of the heap',
                'the bottom of the heap',
                'at the bottom of the heap',
                "'re at the bottom of the heap",
                "we 're at the bottom of the heap",
                "Now we 're at the bottom of the heap"]
```

We have the following set of mappings for the labels of it's constituents:

```
d_non_terminals = {"'re at the bottom of the heap": 'VP',
                   "Now we 're at the bottom of the heap": 'S',
                   'at the bottom of the heap': 'PP',
                   'of the heap': 'PP',
                   'the bottom': 'NP',
                   'the bottom of the heap': 'NP',
                   'the heap': 'NP',
                   "we 're at the bottom of the heap": 'S'}
```

We also have the following set of mappings for the POS tags of it's constituents:

```
d_preterminals = {'Now': 'RB',
                  'we': 'PRP',
                 "'re": 'VBP',
                  'at': 'IN',
                  'the': 'DT',
                  'bottom': 'NN',
                  'of': 'IN',
                  'the': 'DT',
                  'heap': 'NN'}
```

Expected result:

```
out = "(S (RB Now) (S (PRP we) (VP (VBP 're) (PP (IN at) (NP (NP (DT the) (NN bottom)) (PP (IN of) (NP (DT the) (NN heap))))))))"
```

I tried to do using regex based approaches, but I am facing some difficulty in replacing `"S"` with the correct labels.

```
import nltk
import collections

def extract_sentences(sentence):
    t = nltk.Tree.fromstring(sentence)
    return " ".join(item[0] for item in t.pos())


def tree_to_spans(tree, keep_labels=False, keep_leaves=False, keep_whole_span=False):
    if isinstance(tree, str):
        tree = nltk.Tree.fromstring(tree)

    length = len(tree.pos())
    queue = collections.deque(tree.treepositions())
    stack = [(queue.popleft(), 0)]
    j = 0
    spans = []
    while stack != []:
        (p, i) = stack[-1]
        if not queue or queue[0][:-1] != p:
            if isinstance(tree[p], nltk.tree.Tree):
                if j - i > 1:
                    spans.append((tree[p].label(), (i, j)))
            else:
                j = i + 1
            stack.pop()
        else:
            q = queue.popleft()
            stack.append((q, j))
    if not keep_whole_span:
        spans = [span for span in spans if span[1] != (0, length)]
    if not keep_labels:
        spans = [span[1] for span in spans]
    return spans


def get_constituents(sample_string, want_spans_mapping=False, whole_sentence=True):
    t = nltk.Tree.fromstring(sample_string)
    if want_spans_mapping:
        spans = evaluate.tree_to_spans(t, keep_labels=True)
        return dict(collections.Counter(item[1] for item in spans))
    spans = tree_to_spans(t, keep_whole_span=False)  # keep_whole_span=False for error_analysis
    sentence = extract_sentences(sample_string).split()

    constituents = []
    for span in spans:
        i, j = span[0], span[1]
        constituents.append(" ".join(sentence[i:j]))

    # Add original sentence
    if whole_sentence:
        constituents = constituents + [" ".join(sentence)]

    return constituents
```

Comment: Both `d_preterminals` as well as `d_non_terminals` if you see clearly..  `d_preterminals` is the obvious POS tag, whereas `d_non_terminals` are the labels of it's constituents. The function `get_constituents()` spits out the constituents of a given parse string (attached in code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was pretty fun to research, here's what I came up with:

```
tree = nltk.Tree.fromstring(s)
tp = tree.treepositions()

for pos in tp[1:]:              # we're not allowed to assign to the position ()
    subtree = tree[pos]
    if isinstance(subtree, str):    # leaf, so no label
        continue
    else:
        flat_subtree = " ".join(subtree.flatten())
        try:
            correct_label = d_non_terminals[flat_subtree]
        except KeyError:
            correct_label = d_preterminals[flat_subtree]

    tree[pos] = nltk.tree.Tree(correct_label, subtree[:])   # overwrite with new label, but same subtree

print(tree)
```

This gave me following output:

```
(S
  (RB Now)
  (S
    (PRP we)
    (VP
      (VBP 're)
      (PP
        (IN at)
        (NP
          (NP (DT the) (NN bottom))
          (PP (IN of) (NP (DT the) (NN heap))))))))
```

The try-except can be substituted for any logic that tells you in which dict (pre-terminals or non-terminals) to look for.